# Showing x to y of z entries

Tags: php, smarty

I am adding similar to "Showing 1 to 10 of 11 entries" "Showing 11 to 11 of 11 entries" to search result page.

```
$listing_search.listings_per_page = 10
$listing_search.current_page = 2
$listings_number = 11
```

I can't get correct formula.
. Pls share some light.

```
[[Showing ]] {if $listing_search.current_page == 1}1{else}{$listing_search.listings_per_page+1} {/if}
[[ to ]] {$listing_search.listings_per_page}[[ of ]] {$listings_number} {if $listings_number == 1}[[ Job]]{else}[[ Jobs]]{/if}
```

Any recommendation for page 3, 4 and so on? Is that same formula?

I can only tested 11 entries. Here is what I edited.

```
{assign var="current_page" value = $listing_search.current_page}
{assign var="listings_per_page" value = $listing_search.listings_per_page}
{math assign="first_page" equation="(cp - 1) * lpp + 1" cp=$current_page   lpp=$listings_per_page }
{math assign="last_page" equation="(cp  * lpp)" cp=$current_page lpp=$listings_per_page }

<div class="" id="DataTables_Table_1_info">[[Showing ]] {if $first_page}{$first_page}  {else}[[1]]{/if} [[to]] {if $last_page <= $listings_number}{$last_page}{else}  {$listings_number}{/if}
[[of]] {$listings_number} {if $listings_number == 1}[[ Job]]{else}[[ Jobs]]{/if}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Current page's start: `(current_page-1)*listings_per_page +1`
- Current page's end: `current_page*listings_per_page` or `listings_number` (whichever is smaller)

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be something like this:

```
listings_per_page = 10
current_page = 2
listings_number = 11  (I would call this total_listings or something like that)

first_listing = listings_per_page * (current_page - 1) + 1
max_last_listing = (listings_per_page * current_Page)
last_listing = (max_last_listing > total_listings) ? total_listings : max_last_listing
```

that would make first_listing==11
and last listing would be either 20 or the maximum, whichever is smaller.